# Using a css selector to grab a deeply nested button

Tags: html, css, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriver-io

I am currently doing some E2E tests on an app that doesn't have anything to easily identify the tags. I need to click a deeply nested buttons, which on occasion have the exact same name and properties as others.

The HTML code looks something like this:

```
<div class='.ui .row'>
  <div class='.ui .fluid'>
    <div class='.content'>
      <div>
        <div class='.field'>
          <button>Button</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='.content'>
      <div>
        <div>Some other stuff</div>
        <div class='.field'>
           <button>Button</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Because we have two with the same name I couldn't just do `browser.click('button*=Button')`. The way I am currently getting around to it is by this:

`browser.click('div > div > div > div > div > button')`

while the second button, I would have to do something like this:

`browser.click('div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div:nth-child(2) > button')`

Despite it working, I have a few problems with this:
 - it doesn't look pretty and isn't easily readable for someone who may just be picking up this code
- it will go stale with the most minute changes to the app, even if it has nothing to do with the buttons

My question is if there is a better to select these buttons given these circumstances.

Comment: Are there no attributes at all on the elements?

Comment: Yes, but it's just classes a lot of repeated stuff all around the the file (think of bootstrap classes)

Comment: And i'm assuming you don't have access to the markup to make changes?

Comment: can you provide classes as well? or any kind of attributes?

Comment: this may help you https://gist.github.com/LeCoupa/8c305ec8c713aad07b14

Comment: @Tom unfortunately I am currently just testing, so I can't really make any changes to the code.

Comment: @dianoche for the classes, I'll update the OP so you can have an idea of how they are.

Answer (score 2):

If your markup remains similar, you can take advantage of the second button being nested inside a div that is a `sibling` of another div. Example:

```css
/* style the first button */
button {
  color: red;
}

/* style the second button */
div + div button {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <button>Button</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>Some other stuff</div>
        <div>
           <button>Button</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the most easily readable format, Selenium documentation mentions that it falls back to using Sizzle, if a browser doesn't support a query, so you should be able to use `:contains()` which will allow you to select elements via the text they contain, e.g.:

```
button:contains("Button")`
```

etc.

For WebdriverIO, it appears the [syntax](http://webdriver.io/guide/usage/selectors.html#Element-with-certain-text) is slightly different, for using this functionality:

```
browser.getTagName('button=Button'); // captures: "<button>Button</button>"
```

[WebdriverIO documentation](http://webdriver.io/guide/usage/selectors.html#Element-with-certain-text)

[Selenium documentation](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#by-css)

[Sizzle documentation for :contains()](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki#additions)

Comment: I have seen a few answers mentioning that `:contains()` is supposed to work but I've never seen it actually work and I've tried it a few times. Have you used it successfully? Can you provide an example where it works?

Comment: It is very dependent on the environment.  Some environments it works out of the box and some need configuration prior to using it.  However, for this question OP is using WebdriverIO which [claims](http://webdriver.io/guide/usage/selectors.html) to support it out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an XPath

```
//div[.='Some other stuff']/following::button
```

The second button is preceeded by a `DIV` label, "Some other stuff". You can use that to distinguish between the two buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely use Xpath as well :)

Why don't you use the indexing?

for the first one:

```
//button[1]
```

for the last one:

```
//button[last()]
```

Answer (score 0):

There will be plenty of ways to access to the element:

Some examples:

```
// to access the first button 
$$('button')[0].click();

// to access the second button 
$$('button')[1].click();
```

*Note: You can use above if you have only two buttons in that page. If you have more buttons then ideally this should not be used*

Or if you would like to chain the selectors as mentioned here http://webdriver.io/api/utility/$.html

```
let buttonContainer = $('.fluid');
buttonContainer.$$('button')[0].click();
buttonContainer.$$('button')[1].click();
```

Or if you want to access as per the div `.content` then

```
$('.fluid div.content:nth-child(1) >button').click();
$('.fluid div.content:nth-child(2) >button').click();
```

Its up to you how you want to access the `DOM` elements as per your convenience.